# QDialogBox flickers

Tags: qt, modal-dialog, qdialog

I create a custom QDialogBox class and try to display it in the centre of my window using the 'move' command. However, I am facing an issue.

The dialog box appears at a random position on the screen and then moves to the position set by me after 1 second. This happens at random instances. I open the dialog box 10 times and I do not see this flickering. However, this happens the 11th time. There is no specific pattern. Is this a performance issue? This happens more frequently on slower machines.

If I run the dialog box as loginDialog->show(); the flickering is not there. However, it happens when I use: loginDialog->exec(). How can I resolve this issue?

```html
 CustomDialog *loginDialog = new CustomDialog( this );//a QDialogBox class
        float width=350,height=180;
        dialogBoxPosition(&width, &height);
        _mFinalPoint.setX(width);
        _mFinalPoint.setY(height);
        loginDialog->move(_mFinalPoint);//moving it to a window center
        loginDialog->loginWindow();//calling a member function        
        loginDialog->exec();
```

Comment: Try to run profiler.

Comment: This happens all the time. I am testing this on mac. Is this a qt mac problem?